# Is changing the default terminal in elementary OS safe?

Tags: pantheon-terminal, gnome-terminal

I liked the Gnome terminal in Ubuntu but now on Elementary OS I don't find the pantheon terminal as good. I know how to change default terminal. But I want to is it safe ? Will I be able to do all things with the newly installed terminal that I could do with default pantheon terminal ??

Comment: It is safe to do and I can't think of anything that'd not be able to be done in a replacement terminal. In fact, [this link](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8362/how-to-set-alternative-terminal-as-default) will tell you how to set a different default terminal.